# Creating array from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dog:110
    [1] => Cat:111
    [2] => Mouse:101
)
```

Based on that array, I want to create another array to look like this

```
Array
(
   [Dog] => 110
   [Cat] => 111
   [Mouse] => 101
)
```

I know this is easy by creating my own function.  But is there any way to do this with built in php function.  Basically, I know I need to explode(), but is there any way to use this function in conjuction with one php's array functions or will I need to create my own function?

Comment: Don't think there is a way faster than using explode... Perhaps a preg_match, but explode just does the job greatly :) Just loop through the array, explode the string and build the other array :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fun one-liner:

```
parse_str(str_replace(':', '=', implode('&', $array)), $result);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode`

```
$new_arr=array();
foreach($yourarr as $v)
{
 $v = explode(':',$v);
 $new_arr[$v[0]]=$v[1];
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/127708)